# iOS App won't use 4 inch size even with default-568h@2x image

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Everything I read (including on Stack) keeps saying that in order to have an app use the entire 4" iPhone screen you simply have to add a default-568h@2x.png image with a resolution of 1136 x 640.

I've added this image and when I run on a 4" iPhone simulator everything (including the launch image) renders windowed with the black bars at the top and bottom. I've tried deleting and re-adding the image, made sure it shows up as the 4" launch image in the Target summary tab, and adjusted all of the simulated metrics sizes in my storyboard to be Retina 4 full screen.  Even with all of this, I'm still getting the old 3.5" window.

Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Just double-checking, but you didn't simply copy default-568h@2x.png to your project's folder, did you?  Make sure you added it using the XCode project explorer (or whatever it's called), that way the file is actually linked and referenced for use.

Comment: I am in fact, an idiot. As a fair warning to everyone who may encounter this issue, please note that the filename is case sensitive so default-568h@2x.png will not cause the app to run in 4" mode, but Default-568h@2x.png will.

Answer (score 2):

You spelled `Default-568h@2x.png` wrong.  Remember that iOS is a *case sensitive* file system, so the capital "D" matters.  (I had a very similar problem -- which is what led me to this question -- because I was missing the "h" )

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain on what the issue is but a couple more checks you could do would be to make sure you have built the latest version of your project before simulation. The simulator may be launching a previous build that did not have the 4@ images

Maybe try temporarily removing your smaller resolution images to see if that makes a difference.

Also make sure when the simulator is open that you have the correct hardware configuration in the hardware tab

Comment: Double checked that the simulator is indeed using the 4" retina display. Also tried deleting the smaller images, cleaning, and rebuilding. Still have a 3.5" window.

Comment: Do you have a 568@2x splash screen? XCode uses the presence of this splashscreen as a flag telling "This app is compatible with the new 4” Retina screen of the iPhone5"